# Replace strings in body of active email draft

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I want to replace each instance of a given regex with some string in the currently active email draft.

I'm particularly stuck on the first line below.

PseudoCode:

```
myMessage = active message
someRegex = \d\d[:,]\d\d
someString = "(Time Entry)"
myMessage.HTMLBody = Replace(myMessage.HTMLBody, someRegex, someCharacter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work on the first items in Drafts.

Will add further error handling and testing later.

```
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objItemj
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
Set objItem = objFolder.Items(1)

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

objRegex.Pattern = ":\d\d[:,]\d\d"
somestring = "(Time Entry)"
objItem.HTMLBody = objRegex.Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, somestring)
```